# Web App deployed on Azure not returning datetimes in UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core, utc

I have deployed a backend microservice in .net core 3 on Azure and am returning a list of datetime values which i have converted to UTC using `ToUniversalTime()` method. For some reason the datetimes returned are not converted to UTC and are the same values stored in db. It works well when i run it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure Web Apps run in UTC timezone. So for the application, a local time that is read from the database is interpreted to be UTC, hence calling ToUniversalTime does not change the value.
You can specify the timezone for the Web App using the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE setting as described here: https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/tip-changing-an-azure-app-service-time-zone

Comment: What if we use the extension method 
``` TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, timeZone) ``` 
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/feb/10/back-to-basics-utc-and-timezones-in-net-web-apps

Comment: You can use this approach too. Ideal would be to store UTC values in the database and to covert it to the timezone of the user as described in the article. The method in this answer is an easy way to fix it specifically for Azure Web Apps without changing the code, for instance when you cannot change the way the data is störend.

Comment: So the solution seems to store the dates as UTC in database and everythings fine ?

Comment: Yes, this way, you know for sure that the values are UTC (and you do not need to covert them) no matter if the code runs on your system with a TZ other than UTC or in the cloud with UTC.

Comment: Saving my timestamps as UTC datetimes doesn't work either, seems like e bigger frustrating problem ?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Are the values in the database UTC? Local or cloud? When loading the dates from database, is the DateTimeKind UTC?

Comment: I have a table of timespans, which I seed during the db creating, and those values I need to convert to UTC before saving them, but they stay as they are

Comment: If you seed the data in the cloud, the local time is UTC, so converting them to UTC will not change the value that is written to the database. If you run the code locally, I suppose you are not in timezone UTC, so the value changes when you convert a local time to UTC. Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, i have to save some appointment slots like 08:00 - 09:00, i don't know whats the correct way to save them since i cannot convert them to UTC during db creation?

Comment: Do I have to know the timezone of the client to convert these to UTC?